# React Beginner: ERROR Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs

I'm a React beginner and is building my first React app using typescript template. I've got this error "ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')"

Changes I've made after creating template are:

1. Added a component called SuburbSelector.tsx
2. Modified the App.tsx
   I've only used useState in App.tsx. Can someone please help me debug this error? Thanks!

SuburbSelector.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

interface SuburbSelectorProps {
    suburbs: Array<{ value: string; label: string }>;
    onSuburbsSelected: (suburbs: string[]) => void;
}

const SuburbSelector: React.FC<SuburbSelectorProps> = ({
    suburbs,
    onSuburbsSelected,
}) => {
    // handleChange function
    const handleChange = (selectedOptions: any) => {
        if (selectedOptions.length > 3) {
            alert("You can select up to 3 suburbs");
            return;
        }
        if (selectedOptions.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        const selectedSuburbs = selectedOptions.map(
            (option: { value: string }) => option.value
        );
        onSuburbsSelected(selectedSuburbs);
    };

    return (
        <Select
            options={suburbs}
            isMulti
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="suburb-selector"
            placeholder="Select suburbs"
        />
    );
};

export default SuburbSelector;
```

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SuburbSelector from "./components/SuburbSelector";

interface Suburb {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}
const App: React.FC = () => {
    const suburbs: Suburb[] = [
        { value: "1", label: "Orange" }
    ];

    const [selectedSuburbs, setSelectedSuburbs] = useState<Suburb[]>([]);

    const handleSuburbSelected = (selectedSuburbValues: string[]) => {
        // find the corresponding suburb objects based on their values
        const selected = suburbs.filter((suburb) =>
            selectedSuburbValues.includes(suburb.value)
        );
        setSelectedSuburbs(selected);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Suburb Census Comparison</h1>
            <SuburbSelector
                suburbs={suburbs}
                onSuburbsSelected={handleSuburbSelected}
            />
            <div>
                <h2>Selected Suburbs: </h2>
                <ul>
                    {selectedSuburbs.map((suburb) => (
                        <li key={suburb.value}>{suburb.label}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I've asked ChatGPT to debug and it just throws circular conservation which is not helpful

Comment: I copied and test your code and it worked perfectly. When do you see the error?
[Playcode example](https://playcode.io/1725132)